# ¿Cómo cancelar un RedirectToRouteResult en una llamada AJAX?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Estoy intentando enviar información a unos formularios ya hechos, los cuales responden con un `RedirectToRouteResult. Mi intención es ejecutarlo por AJAX y que me respondan con un OK, en caso de que sea de ese tipo la respuesta.

Uso un atributo llamado AjaxResponse en mi código, de esta manera:

```cs
[HttpPost, AjaxResponse(Message = "Ok")]
public ActionResult UpdateDescription(ProviderProfile obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return new NotFoundResult("Proveedor no encontrado.");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return this.RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = obj.User });
    }

    return this.View(obj);
}
```

Este es el código del atributo:

```
public class AjaxResponse : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Message = "Ok";

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() && 
            (filterContext.Result is RedirectResult || 
            filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ContentResult { Content = this.Message };
        }
    }
}
```

Ya confirmé que si se establece el `ContentResult` al `filterContext.Result`, pero aún así, sigo recibiendo el mensaje de redirección en el navegador.

Lo que quiero es recibir un 200 OK, con el mensaje de texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que deberias usar el

[Request.IsAjaxRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest(v=vs.118).aspx)

en el action para detectar como se esta invocando y aplicar una logica u otra

En este caso no realizarias el redirect si es un invocacion ajax

```
[HttpPost, AjaxResponse(Message = "Ok")]
public ActionResult UpdateDescription(ProviderProfile obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return new NotFoundResult("Proveedor no encontrado.");
    }

    if(!Request.IsAjaxRequest)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = obj.User });
        }
    }

    return View(obj);
}
```

**>>Esa era mi idea original, pero mi intención es mover esa lógica a un atributo**

Si revisas la documentacion veras que en realidad esta logica deberias ubicarle en el `OnResultExecuting`

[Understanding Action Filters (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

intenta moviendo alli el codigo que sobreescribe el Result

[Difference between OnActionExecuted and OnResultExecuting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125196/difference-between-onactionexecuted-and-onresultexecuting)

Como observaras en el `OnResultExecuting` puedes cancelar el Result indicado en el action

Comment: Esa era mi idea original, pero mi intención es mover esa lógica a un atributo, sin embargo si configuro `Result`a un nuevo `ContentResult`, sigue ignorando mi código, pero si manipulo `Response`(StatusCode), ya funciona. ¿Será que `OnResultExecuted` no sea el último evento en ejecutarse?

Comment: edite la respuesta, analiza de implementar lo que planteo

Comment: creo que esta confirmado con el link que agregue a la respuesta, debes usar el OnResultExecuting para poder cancelar el Result de redireccion

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, disculpa la tardanza. Saludos.